# Loop through PDFs in Google Drive, display on Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, google-api, google-drive-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a client storing PDFs in a public Google Drive folder. I would like to loop through that folder and display a clickable link (i.e. filename) on my Rails web page. I'm reading through the Google Drive API information here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Can anyone recommend additional methods or tutorials that might be useful for a rails app?

Alternatively, would it be better to use Amazon S3 and Paperclip **EDIT. 5/25/18 Paperclip is deprecated. Active Storage has been recommended for file upload** for file upload and storage? (Not sure I want to go this route. I think my client wants to create his file in Drive and voila! It appears on his web page. Just not sure that's possible.)

Newbie programmer here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of files from a Google Drive folder you'll need to use the [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method from the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/)

In the [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) page I generally find it useful to use the **"Try this API"** to get sample responses from the Google API.

To list all the files for a given Folder ID you'll want to use the following syntax for the `q` parameter:

```
'<folder_id_here>' in parents
```

For example:

```
'1Cz3KdJlzMj-vmN6OMd_nQyUKWlkdsfujo' in parents
```

For Ruby example specific to the Drive API, see:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder

For complete Ruby examples, maybe check out the following:

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help. If you're happy with my answer, it would be great if you could mark it as correct.